# Set max value of stacked area as y-axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to make a stacked area highcharts image. Upon searching for the past two hours to set the y-axis max values as the max value of the stack, I was unsuccessful.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/ms3zcp18/

In the above link, I want the y-axis to be 5268 (doesn't care if it is billions or millions) and not 10. The 10 represents the total 10billion in 2050 but I only want the maximum of 2050 which is 5268 millions as my y-axis. Min value of my y-axis can be 0.

Everyone is speaking about plain charts but stacked area chart max y-axis is not discussed across all forums. I could be wrong too because I only did 2hrs worth of research. And if possible, can the new edit be at the end of javascript file because I am already using the existing javascript file with specific line numbers to make new charts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can do it but as you said it's a stacked chart so you don't see the top value anymore :

```
yAxis: {
   ...
   tickinterval: 5268,
   showLastLabel: false
}
```

**Update:**
[Here a fiddle updated to V2](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/ms3zcp18/3/)

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the SetExtreme and max options. But those values need to be supplied manually. But what I was expecting is to see the highest value of a stack only for the y-axis without disturbing the actual plot.

Comment: You want to see 5268 on the yAxis ?

Comment: Yes. That is right. Just changing the Y-axis max value to the max of a stack is what I am looking into. The plot needs to be unchanged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `max` property only with the value of the highest point, the full range will be cut. So to set the range to show all values, you need to cumulate all stacked values of a specific `x`, and set `max` using value created from stacked `y`. If you have dynamic values, you can update `yAxis` on `load` event for example.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showLastLabel
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/o8yd99je/

Comment: Thanks. But the yaxis label still doesn't catch the 5268 value. It is still at 7.5 billion. What I am asking is to change the label only. Not the actual values of y-axis.

Comment: It is because, as I mentioned in my answer, this is stacked value. If you want plain 5268 value, simply set `max` value with it.